# Shift an existing passport authentication to AWS cognito in nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, amazon-cognito, passport.js

I have an existing nest application, built with postgres and typeorm, I have used passport for authentication, I have also used passport strategies for social login with google, facebook, github and twitter.
Now I need to shift all the authentication to AWS cognito. Is it possible to do so? if which approach should i go for.

I have installed two libraries "@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider" and "amazon-cognito-identity-js" in order to interact with cognito in my backend. I was able to register users in aws cognito but I am a bit confused with social login.

How can I achieve social login with this approach? Do I need to use hosted UI of cognito in order to do the same?